# Bug or Feature?

Tags: python

We recently encountered a troubling problem with python.

Wondering if anybody can explain if this is a bug or feature.

```
array1 = ['a','b','c']
test = array1

del test[2]

print(test)
print(array1)
```

What would you guess the output is?

It is

```
['a', 'b']
['a', 'b']
```

How does the RHS take the value of the left?
Thanks,

Comment: This [blog](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html) has excellent explanation for this behviour.

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature of lists, when you say test= array1 (you are providing an alias to the list), you can reach the desired solution by slicing the list instead.

```
array1 = ['a','b','c']
test = array1[:]

del test[2]

print(test)
print(array1)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not a bug, it is a very knowable feature of python.
If you want to copy  a list you have 2 options:
option1: you can make a shallow copy of the list by putting the RHS in list() constructor.
option2: you can make a deep copy of the list by using the import copy module, and then using the deepcopy method.